# Stopping iPhone app from using Facebook login info

Tags: iphone, facebook

I was playing Hearts Of Vegas on Facebook and once logged into the iPhone app using my Facebook login information.  Recently, the game developer blocked me from the game because I was complaining (long story).

Now, I would just like to play the game on my iPhone app without having anything to do with my Facebook account.  However, the app also blocks me because of the one time of signing in using my Facebook login.  I don’t even get to a screen where I can log out of the Facebook info.  I have tried deleting the app, blocking the app on Facebook, signing out of my Facebook in my safari and deleting the Facebook app, signing out of apple gameroom, and even using a different Apple ID.  Nothing seems to work because when I reinstall the app, it appears that it must still be automatically logging me into the game with my Facebook creditials.  My iPhone must be providing the info to the app automatically once it is launched.

Any advice on how to stop this so I can play the game?  I just don’t know what I’m missing.  Can app developers somehow log identifying information from a specific iPhone?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

9/2/18 update - I spoke with Apple support.  They basically said the only way I can play the app is if I find a way to mask the identifying 2 bits of info the developer has about me through DeviceCheck when I download and reinstall the app.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Apple support was unsure.

Comment: It is likely using cached credentials. The way to get rid of the cache? Delete the app. Then just re-add it. That should do it unless the dev is storing info about your phone on their servers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have deleted the app multiple times and re-added it but it doesn’t work.  What kind of info could the developer store that would identify my iPhone?  I’ve even tried not using my WiFi and just data but the app still blocks me.

Comment: The developer probably stored your login credentials in the iOS keychain. Have you checked Accounts & Passwords in Settings?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!  I just looked through accounts and passwords and nothing for the app.  I went one by one and nothing at all was associated with the app.  I also made sure nothing was in the iCloud regarding the app.

Comment: What about your Facebook credentials, where they in there?  If so, delete it.

Comment: I just deleted the creditials, the Facebook and Messenger apps, and logged out on safari.  Still when I re-install the app, it comes up that I am blocked.  It is so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove personally identifying data (for example tokens or whatnot) that the developer has stored about you in the Keychain on your device, you'll need to not only delete that specific app - but also delete any other app created by the same developer. I.e. other apps that share Keychain access with the problematic app will retain the data.

The developer also has the possibility of storing 2 bits of information unique for your device - the so called DeviceCheck API. The bits are stored at Apple and won't be deleted when you uninstall the problematic app and all other apps by that developer. The developer might have used one of those 2 bits to mean that the user is blocked from using the app.

Comment: I just checked and I have no other apps by the developer so it is not the keychain.  Regarding the DeviceCheck API, is there anyway Apple would delete that if I asked?  That must be the way they are tracking my iPhone.  I can’t believe Apple provides that kind of ID to developers without telling us.

Comment: It is not a secret - Apple has made it very public. It is an improvement upon what was before (also on Android).

Comment: First, thank you for the continued information you are providing.  I greatly appreciate it!  Is it something Apple would help me with or not a chance because they are helping app developers?  I would just want them to delete my “2 bits” from the delevloper info.

Comment: Apple is not "helping the developers" as in being only on the developers side of things. Ordinarily it is the responsibility of the developer to reset DeviceCheck data, if it is being used. So you need to contact the developer first. You can always contact Apple afterwards in case of trouble. BTW: Is your upgraded to the latest version of IOS?

Comment: Yes, I’ve upgraded to the latest version on my iPhone.  Since the developer blocked me for complaints I made, they definitely won’t help me.  I guess my best bet is to contact Apple to see if they can do something on their end.

Comment: I’ve contacted Apple support.  They basically said the only way I can play the app is if I find a way to mask the identifying bits of info the developer has about me when I download and reinstall the app.  Do you know if this is possible?  Apple support was unsure.

Comment: Ask the developer to do it.

Comment: The developer definitely won’t do it since they are the ones who have blocked me for complaining about them on Facebook.  I was hoping there was an app or something that would mask the identifying iPhone bits the developer is using to block me.

Comment: No such app exists. The DeviceCheck bits are not stored on your phone, but rather on Apple's servers. However, you haven't established yet that the developer is indeed using DeviceCheck bits.

Comment: Is there anything else that comes to mind that the developer could be using to continue to block me if they are not using DeviceCheck?

Comment: Not really, nothing else really persists your actions (app deletion, etc) on new versions of iOS. Please remember to mark my answer as accepted.